# What is the mechanism that generates equal numbers of protons and electrons in our universe?

Tags: cosmology, charge, conservation-laws

As far as we know the universe is electrically neutral. An electron-positron pair is easy to create. It is not related to the creation of quarks. So why are there the same number of electrons and protons in our universe? What is the mechanism that generates this?
I have reviewed other questions on this site - but there are no definitive answers.

The same question I am asking was asked here:[proton-electron equality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719836/why-are-the-residual-protons-and-electrons-equal-in-the-universe) Where John Doty invokes charge neutrality: there must be the same number of positive and negative charges in the universe if the universe began in a neutral state, but Anna V in the answer to this similar question [belief of physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/why-do-physicists-believe-protons-and-electrons-are-present-in-equal-numbers) states: conservation of charge does not mean conservation of baryon or lepton numbers. It just means conservation of charge.
This does not answer the question. She goes on to say that the real question is why there is more matter than antimatter in the universe - but this is a completely different question.
In answer to this question [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457961/why-is-there-equal-protons-and-electrons-in-the-universe) Anna V states that this is what we have observed in our universe. This sounds a little like a "That's just the way it is". As far as I know there is no "conservation of equal numbers of protons and electrons law." And yet this is what we find!

What is the mechanism that generates this?

Is it simply unknown or are there are recent theories out there?

Comment: You say "*An electron-positron pair is easy to create.*" Do I understand correctly that you are asking why essentially all of the electron-positron pairs annihilated?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%E2%88%92_L & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543892/123208

Comment: @Sten What I am asking is why there are equal numbers of protons and electrons in the universe. The only mechanism I can think of is that all surviving baryons were initially neutrons which decayed, but I don't think that fits in with the accepted picture of the very early universe.

Comment: We can create an electron (along with a positron) without creating a proton. Similarly, we can create a proton (along with an antiproton) without creating an electron. So, at least for awhile (until annihilation), there *aren’t* equal numbers of protons and electrons. I think the general balance you’re talking about is a consequence of charge conservation *combined with* the fact that the only stable charged particles are protons and electrons. But I’m not a particle physicist.

Comment: You do not realize that "mechanism" like  "theories" are invoked in order to describe measurements and observations and be predictive of new measurements and observations. The world we are in is charge neutral. Our theories are constructed to model this, not to explain it  the way you are asking.  Within existing theories, conservation of charge is imposed to induce charge neutrality, and so within the theories the "mechanism" IS conservation of charge,

Answer (score 1):

In the universe we inhabit, we have no experimental evidence for any process which produces "bare" negative or positive charges in any particle reactions contained in the standard model. Those processes have been looked for and never detected. This strongly suggests that such processes do not in fact exist, at least not at the energy levels currently accessible to us.

This in turn strongly suggests a fundamental constraint in our universe with respect to *charge conservation*, implying an electrically neutral universe in which charges only exist in balanced pairs. Physicists then presume global charge conservation as a fundamental fact, and use it as a constraint on the reasonableness of any proposed model of the functioning of the universe- that is, a universe with charge nonconservation doesn't describe the universe we happen to find ourselves in. .